# doPostBack function issue with scriptresource.axd

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i worked on a page that performing simple db queries , insert,update,delete
 
i use .netframework 4 and sql server 2008 r2 and the page contains only one update panel
 
the scenario is as following:
 
user select a row from gridview and then decide what he want to do (update,delete) 
 
when he click delete button a confirmation modal shows to him , if he said yes then i dopostback

```
           $('#btnExaminationDelete').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#modal-1').modal('show');
            $('#modal-1 #btnConfirm').click(function () {
             __doPostBack('btnExaminationDelete', '');
            });
        });
```

the problem:
when he execute this operation for fist time its ok and no problem 
if he execute this operation for the second time an error occurs in the scriptresource.axd file line 6979 you can see it in firebug's console window

```
              if (isFileUploadRequest) {
                  xhr.send(arguments[0]);
                }
                 else {
                 xhr.send(body);  //this is line 6979
                }
```

if he continue to do the same operation the error appears more than once

i don't know what exactly the cause of problem but i think its fault of __doPostBack function 
this problem occurs in many pages of mine and the page hangs
is there another way to post back from jquery or javascript without __doPostBack function 
what is the solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling __doPostBack directly, can you try to submit a form? with all the required parameters in that form?

```
 $('#btnExaminationDelete').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#modal-1').modal('show');
            $('#modal-1 #btnConfirm').click(function () {
$("#aform #type").val('update');
$("#aform #selected-ids").val('1,2,3');
             $("#aForm").submit();
            });
        });
```

Comment: i tried to do 
$("#Form1").submit();
the whole page is posted back and the btnExaminationDelete_Click method doesn't executed at all

Comment: if you're using gridview, can't you just use command name and onclick function?

Answer (score 0):

finally i found up the solution
simply you have to unbind the Burton before you use click function
the code will be like this

```
     $('#btnExaminationDelete').unbind("click").bind("click",function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#modal-1').modal('show');
        $('#modal-1 #btnConfirm').unbind("click").bind("click",function () {
         __doPostBack('btnExaminationDelete', '');
        });
     });
```

hoping that clear and useful for you